# how use Java CriteriaBuilder to know if date1 and date2 the month between them is less then 12 month

Tags: java, date, jpa

if there a way with [`CriteriaBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) to know if two date is less then 12  month period when building my builder ?

```
Expression<LocalDate> expDate1= root.get("date1");
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(expDate1.toString());
Expression<LocalDate> expDate2 = root.get("date2");
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(expDate2.toString());
Long monthBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(date1, date2);
Predicate predicate= cb.and(monthBetween < 12); // doesnt accept is not a expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to build the criteria. Use the method [lessThan(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lessThan(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) to replace the `<` operator. The same goes for the method [lt(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lt(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)).

Notice that the expression `monthBetween < 12` returns a `boolean` itself, but The method [and(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)) accepts the Predicate as the parameter.

```
Predicate predicate = cb.and(cb.lessThan(monthBetween, 12));
```

Comment: anyway will this create proper sql or rather fetch every record and filter out the result?

Comment: Assume the Hibernate implementation. Using Criteria is the type-safe alternative way to writing explicitly the complicated HQL queries off. Every HQL query is translated into related SQL query before sending that to DB. Anyway, what's the point of your question? The OP is asking the way to build the Criteria, not the performance issue.

Comment: I can verify that myself, but I thought that you may know that. Asking hard questions is what I usually do.